# Load all XML file Tags into a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am a beginner and I want to select an XML file and load it's elements (i.e., a file with tags such as `<item>`, `<title>`, etc.) into a `DropDownList`.

In a separate `TextBox` it should count and show how many times a particular tag or element is present.

When a particular element is selected from the `DropDownList`, the contents, descriptions including the sub-elements in that element should be displayed into a `TextBox`.

I working with ASP.NET and C#.

................................................................................................................

Thanx a lot for all who have read and replied to my Answer. 
Iam using ASP.Net 3.5 only.

Precisly I would explain.........

Example of an XML File
**An XML File**

```
 <Persons>
```

Paxton
    Munich
    29
  
  
    Mike
    Orlando
    33
  
  
    Ella
    LA
    13
  
  
    Zach
    Munich
    32
  
  
    Ingrid
    Oslo
    63

First, I browse and select this XML File.

Second, Load the Xml Tags into a DropDownlist.
       ie. the dropdownlist should contain *Persons, Person, Name, City & Age.*

```
   Now on selecting say **Person** the textbox should Display Message as "The XML File has: 5 Person tags" and SHould display all the Contents under Person tags including its subtags.
```

**Eg:**

```
<Person>
<Name>Paxton</Name>
<City>Munich</City>
<Age>29</Age>
```

Mike
    Orlando
    33
  
  
    Ella
    LA
    13
  
  
    Zach
    Munich
    32
  
  
    Ingrid
    Oslo
    63

this way it should display for any other tags also, such as Name, City, Age, Persons.

```
      In the same way for any other XML File that is selected.
```

My pblm here is, I couldn't load XML **tags** into a Dropdownlist.

Plz Help me

Comment: a XML file can have many levels deep of hiearchical data.... you want to load *ALL* elements into a drop down list? Really? ;-) Can you show us a sample XML and tell us what you want to load from it?

Comment: What version of .NET are you on? 3.5 or higher? In that case you could use Linq-to-XML - otherwise you'll need to use XmlDocument parsing

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not 100% clear but lets take a shot at it.

Firstly lets create a class that has a ElementName property and an XElement property that overides the ToString() method that we can use to populate the dropdown...

```
  public class displayclass
  {
    public string ElementName { get; set; }
    public XElement Element { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
      return ElementName;
    }
  }
```

Then we can easily add the Elements into the Combobox with the Element Name as the text, like so

```
//Some Sample Xml
  XElement xe = new XElement("Root",
    new XElement("Customer",
      new XAttribute("Name", "John Smith"),
      new XAttribute("CreditLimit", 1500)),
    new XElement("Employee",
      new XAttribute("Name", "Fred Nerk")),
    new XElement("Employee",
      new XAttribute("Name", "Sally Silverton")));

  var elemList = from x in xe.Elements()
                 select new displayclass { ElementName = x.Name.ToString(), Element = x };
  foreach (var item in elemList)
  {
    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
  }
```

Now Lets add the count of the Elements into a Text box using a group by clause on our list...

```
  var qry = from dispObj in elemList
            group dispObj by dispObj.ElementName;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (var grp in qry)
  {
    int count = grp.Count();
    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}({1})", grp.Key,grp.Count()));
  }
  textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

And finally lets add an event handler to the selected index change event of the Combobox to display the contents of the element...

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  displayclass disp = comboBox1.SelectedItem as displayclass;
  if (disp != null)
  {
    textBox2.Text = disp.Element.ToString();
  }
}
```

I think this satisfies your reqs as listed above.

Comment: that'll work provided he's on .NET 3.5 or higher - Linq-to-XML didn't exist in .NET 2.0 / 3.0 :-(

Comment: Sure, but I would say to anyone working with XML, get on 3.5 so that you can use Linq to XML.